# Best way to modify this particular model

Tags: modeling

**What My Model Currently Is**
[image: What the model currently is]

Hello Everyone! I am an amateur blender user and I mistakenly added the legs to far forward on my model.

I need to reposition the legs further back, on the y axis of the body of my model. 
I figured there are two ways to do this. Either I detach the legs and move them back or I cutt the butt off and make a new one.

The "Body" of the model is a sphere that has been extruded on the Y axis. 
The "Legs" are a custom extrusion.

What would be the best way to approach this and what tools should I use to accomplish this?

Thank you for being an awesome community and helping on your free time,

Drew :)

**What The Model Is Now**

With help from the community I was able to produce this. A nice mesh with good topology. I realize this model is a little bit more square around the body, but Im starting to like it :)
[image]

Comment: I don't think your topology is good: too many edge loops, some weird ngons, a sphere to make the butt... you should probably try to make something simpler, it will help if you need to to make any modification, here's a quickly made try: https://zupimages.net/up/18/27/k4rj.jpg

Comment: Hi, and welcome to bse. Modelling is, IMHO, one of those pursuits that looks dead easy, and is anything but. Despite _"bad topology et al"_  your model above is instantly recognizable as a dachshund (before seeing the "Dach" in name) .  My suggestion would be to start again with lessons learned.   Use the cube as a starting point. Scale and extrude to shape of torso, inset  faces to extrude legs and neck etc. Use modifiers like mirror and subsurf.

Comment: @moonboots Thank you for the example. I wasnt sure that a square was going to be enough for me so thats why I went for the sphere. Turns out it is! I did try to emulate the legs because what you showed ended up being what I wanted as legs anyways :) You have a better eye for curvature than I do, so I'll be working on rounding out the rear next.

Comment: @batFINGER Between you and moonboots I went back and tried a square and ended up with something that is much much easier to work with. When it comes to adding the head do I just extrude off the top of the cube? When it comes to the tail is it easier to make a seperate shape with a curve for instance and then attach it? I tried extruding one of the faces on the rear but it quickly turned into horns, which I shouldve known it would do.

Comment: yes, always extrude (or inset), do not add with booleans or separate curves, it's only interesting in some cases. When you'll extrude the tail make sure that the Clipping option of the Mirror modifier is enabled, it will stick the vertices on the axis of the mirror. About your new topology: it's much better, you still don't need all these edge loops all along, only add an edge loop when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your topology is good: too many edge loops, some weird ngons, a sphere to make the butt... you should probably try to make something simpler, it will help if you need to to make any modification,

As BatFinger said, start from a mirrored cube, add edge loops when needed, and extrude the different limbs

Here's a quick try:

[image]